# AWS Amplify handling errors from backend

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have a react native app that uses AWS Amplify library (`"aws-amplify":` `"^6.0.13"`) to manage user auth and tokens and making calls to my API Gateway that integrates with Lambda. When I make a call to any endpoint in API Gateway and it returns successful response, I have a proper response object that contains data, status code etc. However, in case if API returns an error I can't see the error message in `catch(error)`. For example, in case of invalid data in a POST call to `myapi/organizations` endpoint in Lambda I throw this code

```
if (!isValidOrgName(orgName)) {
                return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                        .withStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ErrorHelper.buildError(HttpStatusCode.BAD_REQUEST,
                                "Org name should not contain special characters.")));
```

If I send a request via POSTMAN I have an expected response

```
Bad Request 400
{
    "error": {
        "response": {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "body": "Org name should not contain special characters."
        }
    }
}
```

But in case if I call this endpoint with invalid data from react-native using `post` method from "aws-amplify/api" I don't retrieve my error response:

in apiUtils.js:

```
createOrganization: async (body) => {
    const restOperation = post({
      apiName: API_NAME,
      path: "/organizations",
      options: {
        body: body,
      },
    });
    
    const response = await restOperation.response;

    return await response.body.json();
  }
```

In component using apiUtils.js:

```
async function createOrg() {
      try {
        const response = await apiUtils.createOrganization({
          orgName: orgName,
        });
        setOrganization(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error!');
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    }
```

this `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` prints

```
{"name":"UnknownError","underlyingError":{"name":"UnknownError","$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":400,"requestId":"57d5fb7c-5369-4ca7-9874-03b656a9926d","cfId":"xiwoKGxE_Zhbf3OS58Vm4UiY3O8Un87xyTdLQIHYBb1EjZqkdv4AJQ=="}},"$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":400,"requestId":"57d5fb7c-5369-4ca7-9874-03b656a9926d","cfId":"xiwoKGxE_Zhbf3OS58Vm4UiY3O8Un87xyTdLQIHYBb1EjZqkdv4AJQ=="}}
```

I see it returns http 400, but I don't understand what I need to do to retrieve an error message from my lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it in my Lambda with a help of *chrisbonifacio*, who provided an answer here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12997

In handler class:

```
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context) {
        try {
            if (!event.getHttpMethod().equals(SdkHttpMethod.POST.name())) {
                return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                        .withStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
                        .withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ApiError.builder().message("Only POST method is supported").build()));
            }
// other code here...
}
```

ApiError class:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class ApiError {
    private String message;
}
```

In React Native:

```
async function createOrg() {
      try {
        setIsFetching(true);
        const response = await apiUtils.createOrganization({
          orgName: orgName,
        });
        setUserInfo(response);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setIsFetching(false);
      }
    }
```

Now I'm able to get error message via `error.message`